# Select styling is not working

Tags: html, css

```
<select class="form-control" class="venue-type" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="none" id="#hide">Select Venue Type</option>
  <option>Theme Restaurant</option>
  <option>Blah restaurant</option>
  <option>Flana Restaurant</option>
  <option>Woops Restaurant</option>
</select>
```

This is my select list I want no outline border with it

```
select venue-type{
    border: 0 !important;
     -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance:none;
}
```

So I used this css class but it's not working,
it's working with every select I want to edit a particular select

Comment: `select.venue-type` -- you're missing the `.` And no need to write class attribute twice like that -- `<select class="form-control venue-type" ...>`

Comment: Is this "outline" always present or only when the element in question is *focused* on?

Comment: two classes had same name so i changed the name also and used . with combining the classes into one but still not working

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `.` before the class name in your css:

It should be

```
select.venue-type {
  border: 0!important;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gqddn2b1/)**

```
select.venue-type{
    border: 0 !important;
     -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance:none;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<select class="form-control venue-type"  onchange="myFunction()">
                                                <option value="none" id="#hide" >Select Venue Type</option>
                                                <option>Theme Restaurant</option>
                                                <option>Blah restaurant</option>
                                                <option>Flana Restaurant</option>
                                                <option>Woops Restaurant</option>
                                            </select>
```

Comment: @juhi you have written 2 times class="" please write only one time class="select venue-type" 

Here I update answer in "Demo"